# Custom authorization and authentication with old existing database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I want to implement authentication and authorization in my .net 8 project.
The problem is i have an existing old user base, and my own token solution.
I do not want allow any user creation or anything like that.

All i want is that:
When a request comes in, check (id & password) or token against my own database (not entity framework).
And then if correct return my own custom userobject and have this avaible in my controllers.
Token is set as a cookie with a custom cookie name for future requests.

This needs to work with other existing solutions of very old code, and therefore i can't change the underlying logic or databases.

All info and guides i find seem to either be "hello world" level complexity or require special databases set up that would require me to spend years on rebuilding all the other old projects.

What i'm doing currently is require credentials as parameters for all my endpoints and then looking up the user from that inside every controller method